# Kubernetes not making a certificate for SSL

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, cert-manager

I have been trying to enable SSL for my cluster. But, after countless efforts i was failed to do so.

This is my cert-issuer-nginx-ingress.yaml -

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: email@gmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

This is my certificate.yaml -

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: app-dash-board
  namespace: default
spec:
  dnsNames:
    - domain.in
  secretName: app-dash-board-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer 
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

This is my ingress.yaml -

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  name: influx-dashboard
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain.in
    secretName: influx-dashboard-tls
  rules:
  - host: domain.in
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: frontend-service
            port: 
              number: 80
```

I noticed that kubernetes creates a cerficate for this but not using Let's Encrypt -

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: test-selfsigned
  namespace: cert-manager-test
spec:
  selfSigned: {}
```

My domain is hosted on GoDaddy.com. Can anyone help please/?